# I'm having an issue implementing the Command Processor pattern using MVVM for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, mvvm

I'm trying to implement the Command Processor pattern using MVVM for WPF. The Command Processor pattern that I'm roughly following is the one described in the book Pattern-Oriented Software Architecture (Volume 1):

> The Command Processor design pattern separates the request for a
> service from its execution. A command processor component manages
> requests as separate objects, schedules their execution, and provides
> additional services such as the storing of request objects for later
> undo.

My implementation requires that all possible UI actions that may be undoable be stored as commands. This is mostly compatible with WPF's Commands, except for TextBoxes. TextBoxes in WPF don't provide a Command (unlike Buttons and CheckBoxes).

I thought I solved this by adding a `TextChangedCommand` that executes when the `TextChanged` event is raised, like this:

```
<l:CommandTextBox
    Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    TextChangedCommand="{Binding SetNameCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
    />
```

But the problem is that the `TextChangedCommand` is executed not only when the user makes a change but whenever the data-bound property is changed, which happens when undoing the change. In an undo operation, I just want the property to be set to what it was previously, not run a command again.

It's like there needs to be a `TextChangedByUserCommand`, but before I try to implement this I'm wondering if I'm going about this the wrong way, or if someone has come up with a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

My first choice would be to track the operation which is undoing the change and react on the change.

```
private void ResetCommandTextbox()
{
  //some stuff...

  IsViewModelUndoing = true;
  Name = oldValue;
  IsViewModelUndoing = false;
}

public void TextChangedCommand(...)
{
  if(IsViewModelUndoing)
  {
    return;
  }

  // your other stuff which your doing
}
```